# Two positive numbers x and y each of which does not exceed two, are taken at random, the probability that $xy≤1$ and $\frac{y}{x}≤2$ is :

Tags: calculus, probability, definite-integrals, area

> Question: Two positive numbers x and y each of which does not exceed two, are taken at random, the probability that $xy≤1$ and $\frac{y}{x}≤2$ is :

> Answer: The answer of this question is given as $$\frac{3\ln{2}+1}{8}$$

> My approach: I figured out that we would need to apply the method of areas to find this probability, so I need to find out the are bound between $x≤2$, $y≤2$ and the above two given conditions in the question (which are a straight line and a rectangular hyperbola respectively), graphing them gives,

,[image]

Now, in order to find the area bounded between the shaded region common to all the three, I performed the following definite integration, $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{2-2x}\cdot{dx}+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{x}-2x}\cdot{dx}$$ Solving them gives me $$\frac{\ln{2}+1}{2}$$ I am not able to understand where I have gone wrong, please help.

Comment: I can't follow your calculation.  For $x\in \left[0,\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\right]$ the region is bounded on top by $y=2x$.  For $x\in \left[\frac 1{\sqrt 2},2\right]$ the region is bounded on top by $y=\frac 1x$  in both cases, keep in mind that the probability measure is $\frac 14$ times ordinary area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your calculation, in pratice what you should do is the following:$$p = \frac{\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt2}}2x\, dx \space + \int_{\frac1{\sqrt2}}^2 \frac1{x}\, dx}{4}=\frac{3\ln2+1}{8}$$, without much effort. You want the green area of the square, and that's exactly the numerator!